Covariant Derivative of Tensor Fields
In the context of differential geometry, I get most of the idea of covariant derivatives for vector fields but have some trouble interpreting (or making sense if you will) the case for tensor fields. Specifically, from wiki, the covariant derivative of a tensor field is given by

It's weird to say, but I somehow expect the correction term to be positive. I guess this is because of the repeated patterns I saw in Differential Geometry (except when deriving the covariant derivative of co-vector, where we indeed get a negative sign and I understand the reason).

A related post: Covariant derivative of tensors


I'm going to list what I know and why this doesn't make sense:

When dealing with vector fields $X, Y, Z \in \mathfrak{X}(\mathcal{M})$, we have $\nabla(X, Y) := \nabla_X Y$ is defined by requiring three properties: 1) linearity in the first argument; 2) distributivity in second argument: $\nabla_X(Y+Z) = \nabla_X Y + \nabla_X Z$; 3) product rule $\nabla_X fY = f \nabla_X Y + X(f) Y$.
Then by specifying the Christoffel's coefficients, an affine connection is specified.
In a similar fashion, when extending this idea to tensor fields, we would like the following to hold according to the wiki:

Here, I fail to see why requiring these properties yields the given definition.
In parallel, when reading do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry, the covariant derivative of tensor fields is introduced in a brute-forced fashion as:

It is claimed that although we're not starting with the same place, i.e., not first defining some properties of the covariant operator for tensor fields and then proving its existence, this definition is fairly natural in the following sense:

My interpretation of this explanation is that, in this particular moving frame, all the trailing (correction) terms vanish, hence this definition is natural. However, why are we using $-T(\nabla_Z Y_1, \ldots, Y_r) - \ldots$ instead of $+T(\nabla_Z Y_1, \ldots, Y_r) + \ldots$?


It is the other way around.
You want $\nabla_Y$ (a sort of derivative) to distribute equally among all tensors arising in the term $T(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_p,X_1,\ldots,X_q)$ (which is a smooth function) like in the usual Leibniz rule.
Here, the tensors involved are $T$, $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_p$, and $X_1,\ldots,X_n$.
So in the particular case where $T$ is a $1$-form and $X$ a vector field, this yields
$$
\nabla_Y(T(X)) = (\nabla_YT)(X) + T(\nabla_YX),
$$
and in the general case, you want something like
\begin{align}
\nabla_Y\left(T(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_p,X_1,\ldots,X_q)\right)
&= (\nabla_YT)(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_p,X_1,\ldots,X_q) \\
&\quad + T(\nabla_Y\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_p,X_1,\ldots,X_p) \\
&\quad + \ldots \\
&\quad  + T(\alpha_1,\ldots,\nabla_Y\alpha_p,X_1,\ldots,X_q) \\
&\quad  + T(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_p,\nabla_YX_1,\ldots,X_q) \\
&\quad  + \ldots \\
&\quad  + T(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_p,X_1,\ldots,\nabla_YX_q).
\end{align}
Isolating the term involving $(\nabla_YT)$ yields minus signs for all other terms but $\nabla_Y(T(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_p,X_1,\ldots,X_q))$.

I see. So this makes sense for the wiki definition. I failed to see this first when reading do Carmo since I didn't internalize tensors well enough that it will output a smooth function so actually $Y(T(\ldots)) = \nabla_Y(T(\ldots))$.

@pbb Do Carmo defines exactly the same thing. It should be read as a definition in this way: "$(\nabla T)(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n;Z) := (\nabla_ZT)(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$".

Right, I get that part. I was referring to the fact that $Y(f) = \nabla_Y f$ where $f = T(\ldots)$.
